# c++/cli wrapper question

Tags: c++-cli

Is there a recommended way to wrap a native c++ library by c++ cli?

Comment: What do you mean? I think that entirely depends on what you are trying to accomplish. So. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: You can use native C++ library in C++/cli without 'wrapping' it.

Comment: You can't, no good way to pinvoke the constructor and destructor calls.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure if one size fits all, but yeah, it is largely a mechanical process.  Your ref class wrapper should declare a private member that's a pointer to your native C++ class.  Create the instance in the constructor.  You'll need a destructor and a finalizer to delete that instance again.

Then for each function in the native C++ class you write a managed version of it.  That's almost always a one-to-one call, you simply call the corresponding native method and let C++ Interop convert the arguments.  Sometimes you have to write a bit of glue code to convert a managed argument to the native version of it, particularly if your native method uses 8-bit char* or structure arguments.

You'll find that standard pattern in code in [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691325/c-cli-mixed-mode-dll-creation/2691448#2691448).  I also should mention SWIG, a tool that can automate it.  Not sure how good it is, never used it myself.