# c++ managed and unmanaged static library

Tags: .net, c++, unmanaged, managed, regasm

I have a some managed C++ assembly with simple code.

This assembly has mixed (managed/unmanaged) code. If I put unmanaged code to the separate unmanaged static library and link it with managed code then I get registration error like this: ***"Failed to load 'xxxxxx.dll' because it is not a valid .NET assembly".***

If I put all code to one project and build it together then all works finely. I have tried it on VS2008 + .NET3.5 + RegAsm .Net2.0. My assembly is signed.

I would like to save my code separation for unmanaged static library and managed assembly.

What I need to do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How possibly can it contain "mixed code"?.. Are you talking about "unsafe code" instead? it's still managed then..

Comment: no he is talking about a mixed mode assembly see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0w2664k.aspx

Comment: deleted my answer because it was wrong.  take a look this related SO question which I think will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691325/c-cli-mixed-mode-dll-creation

Comment: It's auto-answer ;-). I have done some experiments and here some my issues: 1. If you want to use static libraries with unmanaged code into managed C++ project then you need to compile it with /clr option. 2. Be carefull with optimization of unmanaged library's code (sometimes I have got the message like "...damaged library image" during release compilation of the managed project). 3. If you want to work with pure unmanaged code (without /clr compilation) and small time and space overhead then try to include unmanaged code like unmanaged dll library (I am using boost library like dll). IMHO

Answer (score 1):

Your lib must be built to use the C++ runtime dynamically (as of .NET 2.0).

In project properties, open C/C++, and go to Code Generation.  Look for Runtime Library, and set to Multi-threaded DLL for release, and Multi-threaded Debug DLL for debug.