# Convert .lib and .h files to .NET

Tags: c#, c++, clr, pinvoke, unmanaged

A brokerage firm has an API built around C++ provided as a library and header files for users to consume(orders, prices, news..etc), long story short, I only have practical knowledge of C# and would like to make use of some wrapping technologies to make use of the .lib and .h files provided by converting them into managed DLLs. Is there a way of doing this without getting involved in much C++ coding/wrapping?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++/CLI Mixed Mode DLL Creation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691325/c-cli-mixed-mode-dll-creation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use C++/CLI. Try to [starts from here](http://www.functionx.com/cppcli/index.htm).
Basically I would create a C++/CLI wrapper in order to expose a wise set of functionality to c#.
Anyway, it is not an easy task.
An alternative is to write in pure c++ some extern "C" entry point to the library and access that api using P/Invoke.