# wrapper class for C++ in .net?

Tags: c#, c++

I am having a C++ project. i would like to port it to a C#.NET project. I have done some research and I think the most popular way is to use pinvoke.

I dont know whether there are also other methods existed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use native COM components from C#

Comment: That's a bit unlikely, you can't use pinvoke to use C++ classes.  C++/CLI required.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691325/c-cli-mixed-mode-dll-creation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, plain P/Invoke is good to interface with C, but if you want to interop with some real C++ code, you would have to use something more sophisticated. With .NET, you can use C++/CLI. On Mono on and .NET you can use:

- [CXXI](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2011/Dec-19.html)
- [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/)

First option is less mature but seems to be more elegant.

Answer (score 6):

You can:

1) Rewrite the entire project in C#

2) Reuse several components using either:

- [P/Invoke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_Invocation_Services) to reuse unmanaged compiled code

  or
- [C++/CLI](http://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++/CLI) to create wrapper classes

Answer (score 1):

You could use **[C++/CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++/CLI)** to create wrapper classes.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/).