# Writing unmanaged C++ DLLs for use in C#

Tags: c#, c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, dll

I'm a Linux C++ developer, and I need to write C++ dlls for windows, which is to be used in C# applications.

The problem is importing the DLLs into C#, which I have no idea how to do it. In my friends' project its probable that any kind of unmanaged dll will be used, and I'm charge of doing this :-D

I need to import all objects and functions in the DLL, and my search has led me to nothing more than DllImport and so.

Thanks so much for helps.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++/CLI Mixed Mode DLL Creation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691325/c-cli-mixed-mode-dll-creation)

Answer (score 2):

You can use C++/CLI as a wrapper for your unmanaged C++.For more info on C++/CLI and what it does you can use this link

http://www.functionx.com/cppcli

You can have a quick look at this

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19354/Quick-C-CLI-Learn-C-CLI-in-less-than-10-minutes#A8

Comment: Thanks for the link. And does it mean that I must touch my C++ code to conform with CLI? I just compiled my C++ code again in VC++ with the clr option enabled, and I its possible now to import it in C# but I don't see it's contents there in object browser. What to do?

Comment: Export the class of c++ which you want to use in c# through dllexport and then use the lib file generated as an external dependency in your C++/CLI project.The make C++/CLI project as a dll and write wrapper class for your C++ code .Use this managed dll in your C# code

Comment: Well, I found the answer I was looking for, here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173265(v=vs.80).aspx, and I can simply precede the class definition with **public** and access it in C#, but public doesn't work with functions, defined in global namespace besides classes. How may I do that?

Comment: Yes newbie, you're right. And I found the way to do it as I asked in another question after this one. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

you want DllImport

There's a bunch of info here :-

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468(v=vs.71).aspx

and lots lots more all over google, and many stackoverflow questions related to DllImport

Comment: That's right, but DllImport doesn't import objects, and what am I supposed to do in case of dlls including objects with big definitions? lots of member functions, etc.?

Comment: then your better option is to go for compiling your C++ as CLR code.   But even then, you have to do a bit of work as not all C++ basic types nicely interface with .NET.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to go about this. You can write a CLR dll in C++ which puts an interface that C# can directly "talk" to. This is a nice option cause you can keep native C++ still and not have all of your code be CLR based.

Do some searches for C++/CLI

You can also use dllimport and friends and create a standard dll.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought to keep the Dll's in C++ (port then recompiled under VS.NET) less effort than a C# port.

I have in the past made a shared memory DLL to allow LabVIEW (Windows7) and a Winforms C#.NET appl. to share data storage via this dll.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this tutorial. It shows two methods for accomplishing what you want: [How to Marshal a C++ Class](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18032/How-to-Marshal-a-C-Class)