# Mixing managed/unmanaged C++?

Tags: c++, c++-cli

I have a library written in standard C++. I also have a .Net windows form app written in C# that utilizes the unmanaged library.

I understand I can just use pinvoke, but my C++ is completely OO and I really wouldn't want to mess around with marshaling and such.

Is there a way that I can just create a new managed C++ dll project, copy and paste my header and code files, and compile it and have access to all the classes?

Or would I have to create some ref class in managed c++ and hook it up to my unmanaged class? I just want this to be as simple as possible.

Thanks!

Comment: C++/CLI is mixed managed/unmanaged by nature.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++/CLI Mixed Mode DLL Creation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691325/c-cli-mixed-mode-dll-creation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would still have to write specific .NET wrappers even in C++/CLI, they just look different. So the answer to, can you put it in a C++/CLI project and recompile and use it as is, is no. You still have to either marshal the data over (in which case you may as well use p/Invoke probably) or you can create handles and use pinned memory to make your structures available to managed code.

I've done this both ways: I've written a GPU library in CUDA C and called it from F# using p/Invoke and I've written a video processing library in C++ and written a thin C++/CLI wrapper then used it in a .NET app. I think the CLI wrapper was more painful, but for live video I needed less latency (less copying memory). For the GPU project I was more concerned with throughput.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably going to want to write the wrapper classes in C++/CLI. It's fairly trivial to do, as long as you return handles instead of pointers, enumerators instead of collections, etc.