# import native c++ classes

Tags: c++-cli

I've got c++/cli class library project. I need to import c++ native clases. they are declared like this

```
class __declspec(dllexport) Check
{
   const char* type;
protected:
   int val;
public:
   Check(int);
   Check();
   const char* Type();
   void Type(const char*);
   virtual int Val();
   void Val(int);
   ~Check(){};
};

class __declspec(dllexport) Test:public Check
{
    const char* type;
public:
    Test(int x);
    int Val();
    ~Test(){};
};
```

how to import them into c++/cli project?(I've got .dll and .lib files)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't "import" native code, it doesn't have anything resembling the metadata in a managed assemblies that describes the types.

You have to do this the old-fashioned way.  You must use #include in your source code to include the .h header file(s) that declare the classes.  Wrap those #includes with #pragma managed(push, off) and #pragma managed pop to ensure the compiler understands these are native code declarations.  Also beware that the declarations you posted are not good enough, the classes must appear with the __declspec(dllimport) attribute.  You normally use a macro for that.

And you must tell the linker to link the .lib, the import library for the DLL.  Project + Properties, Linker, Input, Additional dependencies setting.

You'll find more hints on writing managed class wrappers in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691325/c-cli-mixed-mode-dll-creation).

Comment: Better yet, forget about `dllexport` and the import library, and just have a mixed-mode assembly that contains both the native implementation and the managed wrapper in a single binary.