# C++ program hosting .net exposing objects from C++ to C#

Tags: c#, c++, scripting

i'm exploring the idea of use .net as a scripting language for my program.

i found a lot of examples on internet that shows how to host .net and then, from c++ call functions from .net.

But i need to go on the other way too, from this code in c#, i need to be able to create/call c++'s objects from this c# script, so i need to expose functions/objects to control it from C#.

How can i do it?

Simple Example to show what i'm talking about
I call my c++ method "CreateGUI". It'll call .net code: "InitializeGUI", and this "InitializeGUI" need to check if an object (for example, the texture) is instantiated inside C++.

Can someone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Write managed wrappers for your C++ classes with the C++/CLI language.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691325/c-cli-mixed-mode-dll-creation for an example.

Comment: Hm, I'd love to know how do you want to use ".Net as a scripting language for your program..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use managed C++, you can create a managed C++ component which can be called from your C# code. If you use unmanaged C++, you can either create a C++ COM component and use it through C# via RCW (Runtime Callable Wrapper) mechanism or you can create a C++ dll and call it from C# via PInvoke.

Comment: OK, i tried it but not the right result.<br/>I created a singleton class into a static library, created a c++ managed dll to expose some methods from this static library, created a c# dll referencing this managed dll, then i crea

Comment: OK, i tried it but not the expected result. I created a singleton class inside a static library, created a c++ managed dll to expose some methods from this static library, created a c# dll referencing and using this managed dll, then i created a c++ program that hosts .net and execute my .net dll. the problem is, when i call the methods from the singleton, the object is different when i call it directly from c++ and c#. how i can make both worlds see the same object? Thanks!

Comment: OK, solved it, instead of calling the singleton i passed the pointer to the .net, this way i can call my original object.

Comment: for reference, i used this page http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/299da822-5539-4e5b-9ba7-b614e564c9f4/ and this http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CppHostCLR-e6581ee0/view/SourceCode#content

Answer (score 0):

You might also investigate Mono, which is [explicitly intended to be embedded](http://www.mono-project.com/Embedding_Mono) and will run any compiled .NET assembly, meaning the full powers of C#, VB.NET, even F# will be available.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I thought about using it but can i debug mono from mixed applications?

Comment: Depends on which debugger you use - of course you can debug with gdb or windbg.  I've never tried to use VS on a program that embedded mono - or .NET, for the matter.