# Is it possible to create a variable from native C++ class in C#?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, visual-c++, c++-cli

There are two separate project which are trying to communicate like this :
I have following **native** class in C++ CLI

```
public class Data{
    public:
    int x;
}
```

By importing I mean that have added reference to C++ CLI project in my C# project.
On other side I'm importing this C++ CLI project into my C# project and in C# I want to do :

```
Data k = new Data() //It's ok till here
int b = k.x; //The field x is not visible here !
```

Is there any way to force C# or C++ CLI to share the field and methods ?
*EDIT: Also C# assume the `class data` as a `struct` !*

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "importing into your C# project".  You can't have C# and C++ CLI in _one project_.  Do you mean you're referencing the CLI _assembly_ from your C# project within _one solution_?

Comment: @DStanley I have edited my answer, please check it again.

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine you would need to make it a `ref class`.

```
public ref class Data{
    public:
    int x;
}
```

C# can't construct `Data` in the way you have it now. It's not on the managed heap. `ref` will make it show up on the managed heap. If you want `Data` to remain unmanaged, you will have to write a wrapper.

Comment: Yes I could do that, but as you see it's a native class. Which is also bold in my answer. I can't use managed class there.

Comment: Can you shed some light how to write the wrapper ?

Comment: @Mahdi then i'm afraid you can't just interop like that.

Comment: I'm sure there should be a way to achieve this because the class Data is visible to my C# project.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691325/c-cli-mixed-mode-dll-creation/2691448#2691448