# How to make VC 2015 generate a DLL and not just a lib file?

Tags: c, visual-studio, dll, visual-studio-2015

I'm building [SDL_pnglite](https://github.com/lxnt/SDL_pnglite) from source, in Visual Studio 2015.  I've gone through and added references to the proper .h and .lib files for its dependencies (zlib and SDL2), and I set Configuration Properties->General->Project Defaults->Configuration Type to DLL.

When I build, it builds successfully, but it only generates a .lib file and not a .dll.  What am I missing?  In the past, all I've ever needed to build a .dll was that Configuration Type setting, but this time it's not working.

Comment: You probably are not exporting any symbols. When no symbols are exported in a dll project the dll is not generated. Here is some info on how to export: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27998/exporting-a-c-class-from-a-dll/28018#28018