# Why is Visual Studio ignoring an .h file in my project?

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

When I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35114764/how-to-make-vc-2015-generate-a-dll-and-not-just-a-lib-file) about trying to build a DLL and not getting one, a commenter mentioned that I was probably not exporting any symbols in the project.  When I checked, I found that the project file CMake had built didn't contain the .h file for the project, so I added it.  It contains the needed export declarations.  Unfortunately, rebuilding still doesn't generate a DLL, and after playing around a little, I find that the compiler doesn't seem to notice the .h file at all; when I write things in there that are obviously syntactically invalid, it doesn't even break the build.

Why is the compiler ignoring the .h file after I added it to the project, and how can I get it to compile properly?

Comment: Is the .h file #include'd in any .c file that's compiled with the project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler will only translate a .h file if it is *included* in a translation unit (.c file) that it is building.  Adding a reference to it the makefile does not in itself cause the .h file to be translated.  If it is a *target* - there is no rule to build a .h file because it makes no sense.  If it is a *dependency*, changes to it will cause the target to be built, but if the target does not include the header file, it is not a true dependency.

Another possibility is that the header is included but includes some conditional compilation that is not enabled.

Comment: Ugh, right.  I should have remembered that #include is all inline.  Sorry; I'm too used to languages with real module systems.